# robust linear regression with lapply

Tags: r

I'm having problems to run a robust linear regression model (using rlm from the MASS library) over a list of dataframes.

Reproducible example:

```
var1 <- c(1:100)
var2 <- var1*var1
df1  <- data.frame(var1, var2)
var1 <- var1 + 50
var2 <- var2*2
df2  <- data.frame(var1, var2)
lst1 <- list(df1, df2)
```

Linear model (works):

```
lin_mod <- lapply(lst1, lm, formula = var1 ~ var2)
summary(lin_mod[[1]])
```

My code for the robust model:

```
rob_mod <- lapply(lst1, MASS::rlm, formula = var1 ~ var2)
```

gives the following error:

```
Error in rlm.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

How could I solve this?

The error in my actual data is:

```
Error in qr.default(x) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: as you can see here `?lm` provides only a formula method. In contrast `?rlm` provides both (formula and `x,y`). thus, you have to specify `data` to say `rlm` to use the formula method as in Rui Barradas answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call is missing the `data` argument. `lapply` will call `FUN` with each member of the list as the *first* argument of `FUN` but `data` is the *second* argument to `rlm`.

The solution is to define an anonymous function.

```
lin_mod <- lapply(lst1, function(DF) MASS::rlm(formula = var1 ~ var2, data = DF))
summary(lin_mod[[1]])
#
#Call: rlm(formula = var1 ~ var2, data = DF)
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-18.707  -5.381   1.768   6.067   7.511 
#
#Coefficients:
#              Value   Std. Error t value
#(Intercept) 19.6977  1.0872    18.1179
#var2         0.0092  0.0002    38.2665
#
#Residual standard error: 8.827 on 98 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: It would also suffice I think to not use the anonymous function and instead directly call the formula method via `MASS:::rlm.formula`.

Comment: @joran But then how would `lapply` know where to put the list members? The problem would be the same.

Comment: It would work exactly the same as with `lm`. Try it, it works: `lapply(lst1, MASS:::rlm.formula, formula = var1 ~ var2)`.

Comment: thank you, that helped a lot. Why does my code work for the linear model though? The order of the first arguments of the two functions looks similar in the documentation.

Comment: @felixR Rui's answer is correct, but the explanation is perhaps a little confusing. The issue isn't really the order of the arguments, it's the existence of the additional S3 method, as mentioned in the other answer. That creates some ambiguity in the dispatch and so the default method is called for `rlm` instead of the formula method. Either calling that method directly, or specifying the other argument both force the use of the formula method.

Comment: @joran That is why I prefer the anonymous function. Unless there is no ambiguity, which is not the case.

Comment: Thank you guys, really well explained.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try a `purrr:map` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1, ~rlm(var1 ~ var2, data=.))
```

or as joran commented

```
map(lst1, MASS:::rlm.formula, formula = var1 ~ var2)
```

As you can see here `?lm` provides only a formula method. In contrast `?rlm` provides both (`formula` and `x, y`). Thus, you have to specify `data=` to say `rlm` to explicitly use the formula method. Otherwise `rlm` wants `x` and  `y` as input.